# CREATE OLAP server

Tags: mysql, replication, myisam, olap

I have a MySQL database server along with replication server, i.e. OLTP system altogether.

As I have very heavy data fetching queries for the decision making reports. I need to create data-ware house OLAP system, a separate OLAP server, with all OLTP tables but all tables will be MyISAM. So I can fetch & aggregate the data faster.

So, I need to create procedure which runs,say once in a two days or weekly. which requires incremental dumps from (replication server) and apply those dump on my OLAP server.

Can any expert please suggest me how to accomplish this from the very start.

I have a CENTOS server with LAMPP.

Comment: From the very start, realize that InnoDB will be better.  Also, plan on building Summary Tables -- and do the "reports" against them, not against the Fact tables.

Comment: Please specify estimated sizes and ingestion speed.  Also, purge policy -- this may lead to including `PARTITIONing`.

Comment: I dont want to use InnoDB in my data ware house, As dataware house doesnt need any transactions.  for fetching MyISAM is better i guess. and I already have crons for  Summary Tables/aggregation. however it all resides in OLTP.  there are some reports which directly run from OLTP. so it effects OLTP operations. So I want all analytical work to be moved in data warehouse and want to make OLAP system.

Comment: hello @RickJames the database size as of now is around 200 GB. it has data of say last 7 - 8 years. it grows around 150 MBs/day  in week days. So I want to take incremental backup of 150 MBs and load it in my data warehouse. I shall also think to take this incremental backup on weekly basis of once in a two days.  purge policy is not there right now. There is a replication server of OLTP and we take day-to-day FULL backup on daily basis from replication server

Comment: I am hearing that purging is not important.  What version of MySQL are you using?  "Transportable tablespaces" is one way to move chunks of data easily.  Otherwise, `SELECT` is the likely tool.

Comment: More on [transportable tablespaces](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-4-now-supports-transportable-tablespaces-for-innodb-partitions/).  That link talks about 5.7, but has a section "But how to do this in 5.6?"

Comment: thank you, I will do some RnDs based on mentioned article.